# Cannot create pgr_PointsAsPolygon from pgr_DrivingDistance function?

Tags: postgis, pgrouting, osm2pgrouting

I have successfully build a pgr_DrivingDistance query,

```
select 
    id::int4,
    lon::float8 as x,
    lat::float8 as y
from 
pgr_DrivingDistance(
    'select gid as id, source, target, length as cost from ways',
    23199, 
    0.01, 
    false
) as isokron inner join ways_vertices_pgr on (isokron.node = ways_vertices_pgr.id)
```

to have successfully have an id, x, and y column for the output.

I want to use that output into pgr_PointsAsPolygon function, which will create a polygon from the (x, y) pair above.

But I'm having difficulty in building the combined. I try these, but without result.

```
select pgr_pointsAsPolygon(
'select 
    id,
    lon as x,
    lat as y
from 
    pgr_drivingDistance(
        ''select gid as id, source, target, length as cost from ways'',
        23199, 
        0.01, 
        false
    ) as isokron inner join ways_vertices_pgr on (isokron.node = ways_vertices_pgr.id)');
```

It keeps telling me this error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "select"
LINE 7:    'select gid as id, source, target, length as cost from wa...
            ^
QUERY:  SELECT x, y FROM pgr_alphashape('select 
    id,
    lon as x,
    lat as y
from 
    pgr_drivingDistance(
        'select gid as id, source, target, length as cost from ways',
        23199, 
        0.01, 
        false
    ) as isokron inner join ways_vertices_pgr on (isokron.node = ways_vertices_pgr.id)', 0)
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function pgr_pointsaspolygon(character varying,double precision) line 17 at FOR over EXECUTE statement
********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "select"
SQL state: 42601
Context: PL/pgSQL function pgr_pointsaspolygon(character varying,double precision) line 17 at FOR over EXECUTE statement
```

I've tried create the polygons (pgr_pointsAsPolygon) using all the vertices (without using pgr_drivingDistance) and it worked perfectly!

Whats wrong with the code?
Is the double single-quote escape wrong?

Comment: As i search for answers, I know that this kind of problem can be solved by using VIEW..  but why does the query above doesnt work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We mentioned this issue in the pgRouting Practical Guide - http://locatepress.com/pgrouting (still in draft). Hopefully will be fixed in later pgRouting versions.

The work around is to do this (as DavidP pointed out using $$ is a first step), but the bug is that you still need '' in the inner query where as you really shouldn't need that:

```
SELECT pgr_pointsAsPolygon(
 $$ SELECT 
   id,
    lon as x,
    lat as y
FROM 
   pgr_drivingDistance(
    ''SELECT gid as id, source, target, length as cost from ways'',
    23199, 
    0.01, 
    false
) as isokron 
inner join ways_vertices_pgr 
   on (isokron.node = ways_vertices_pgr.id) $$);
```

Comment: Referencing the issue on Github to be able to see, if it has been resolved: https://github.com/pgRouting/pgrouting/issues/550

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your query is translated inside pgr_pointsAsPolygon into another query with bad syntax - multiple single quotes inside one string (look at the QUERY part of error message). I would try to replace double quetes ('') with $$ or you can use CTE syntax:

```
WITH isokron AS (
select 
    id::int4,
    lon::float8 as x,
    lat::float8 as y
from 
pgr_DrivingDistance(
    'select gid as id, source, target, length as cost from ways',
    23199, 
    0.01, 
    false) a
inner join ways_vertices_pgr b on (a.node = b.id)
)
SELECT
pgr_pointsAsPolygon(
'select 
    id,
    lon as x,
    lat as y
from isokron')
```

Comment: This won't work because the isokron is an alias name only valid within the CTE so not visible tot eh pgr_pointsAsPolygon.

Comment: @LR1234567 I'm bit smarter now...

Comment: @LR1234567 what is CTE?

Comment: @KeenanGebze you can find more about CTE (Common Table Expression) in Postgres docs here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/queries-with.html